# How to run a function using SU or the whole entire app in Superuser - kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, arp, superuser

I'm making a kivy app in where i'm scanning the ipv4, using arp, now for this superuser is required.

But i'm struggling to either run the function via super user or the whole entire app, whatever works.

Thanks for the help.

What i tried:
cmd = ['su', '-c', 'python', '-c', name_function]
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print(output)

or calling su using subprocess on startup - does absolutely nothing.

Comment: You have to root your phone before doing this for example using Magisk. Do you have a su binary installed?

Comment: Also I doubt kivy comes with a python binary. Perhaps you have to write a native program which is typically compiled using the Android NDK and executed by su.

Comment: @zomega I'm indeed rooted.. about the NDK i'm not sure as i hadn't tried it. - i also doubt that it'll solve it